# Powershell escape for variables that contain passwords

Tags: powershell

So I am using a variable that contains a password and just recently found out that some of the passwords are containing special characters. I have no control over what the password is so I have to deal with whatever I am getting. I know the back tick '`' character is what is used to escape characters. The whole reason for this post is that I am finding passwords is text files and replacing the found password with a pattern of 'xxxxxxxxx'.

Currently the code I am using is this:

```
$pass = "DR$123asd##!"
```

Because the $pass variable contains the '$' character the $123asd is seen as a variable that has no value

```
$pass
```

so all you get is:

```
DR##!
```

If I change the pass variable like this

```
$pass = 'DR$123asd##!'
$pass
DR$123asd##!
```

Then the '$' character is ignored and the string is complete, but If I run the code:

```
$output | foreach-object { $_ -replace "$pass", 'xxxxxxxx' }
This is my password DR$123asd##!, It is a great password!
```

The password doesn't get replaced and I'm, not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-replace` is a regular expression operator, and the `$` sigil is indeed a special character in regex.

You can escape all regex meta-characters in a literal string with `[regex]::Escape()`:

```
$output | foreach-object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape("$pass"), 'xxxxxxxx' }
```

Comment: yes it does, thank you. I was not aware of being able to use [regex] that easily. I knew it would probably come down to a regular expression but that is easy. Awesome...thanks.